# How to know where resolv.conf entries come from?

Tags: debian, dns, openvpn, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I use resolvconf for nameserver management because my OpenVPN requires it. However, I notice that it generates nameserver information that is not exactly how I would want it:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 173.31.45.181
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search lan 8.8.8.8
```

Each directive here is undesired when I'm not connected to VPN, except `nameserver 8.8.8.8`. How do I know why resolvconf puts a particular entry? Is there a way of discerning i.e. what program wants `nameserver 192.168.1.1` to be there? I tried `man resolvconf` but it doesn't provide the answer.

Comment: NetworkManager service automatically modifies your /etc/resolv.conf  file.    Disable this service and manually create the file.

Comment: I use wicd and disabling it results in loss of connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/etc/resolv.conf` is built from pieces that are in the directory `/run/resolvconf/interface` (actual location on current Debian and Ubuntu) `/etc/resolvconf/run/interface` (old location, still existing via a symbolic link on Debian). Each piece is named after the interface that it is associated with.

When they aren't static, the entries in `/etc/resolvconf/run/interface` are normally set from static configuration in [`/etc/network/interfaces`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&sektion=5), from scripts executed from [`/etc/network/if-*.d`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&sektion=5), or by services that set up network connections such as NetworkManager, wicd or OpenVPN. For example, OpenVPN comes with a script `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` that is normally called by the OpenVPN client configuration.

Comment: `/run/resolvconf/interface` rather than `/etc/resolvconf/run/interface` on my system.

Comment: @Mikel In jessie `/etc/resolvconf/run` is a symlink to `/run/resolvconf` (at least on a typical new or upgraded systems, there are a lot of special cases in `resolvconf.preinst` and `resolvconf.postinst`). Was the symlink dropped in stretch?

Comment: Mine's Ubuntu 15.10 (wily).

Comment: Definitely correct answer! However, I still can't see `/etc/resolvconf/run/interface` mentioned in a manpage you've linked to...

Comment: @Red Indeed the man page doesn't mention the `interface` subdirectory. It isn't something that you should modify, but it can be useful to look there in situations like yours where you wonder where a line comes from.